# Can i make a selector for what class to bind with the css binding in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

Are there an easier way to do this than:

```
 <div data-bind="css: { high: selectedPriority() == 1, medium: selectedPriority() == 2}">
```

I have up to 6 steps? Alternative bind the attribute class and write the hole class list in js.

Answer (score 0):

In Knockout 2.2 (in RC as of 18 Oct 2012), you can give the `css` binding a class to set:

```
<div data-bind="css: priorityClass"></div>
```

`priorityClass` can then be a computed observable in your view model:

```
vm.priorityClasses = {1:'high', 2:'medium' /*...*/};
vm.priorityClass = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.priorityClasses[this.selectedPriority()];
}, vm);
```

If you don't want the computed observable, you could put that logic directly in the binding:

```
<div data-bind="css: priorityClasses[selectedPriority()]"></div>
```

Until 2.2 is released, you can use the [class custom binding](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---class) instead.